# MySQL/PHP - Auto update column after certain time has passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I've recently came across an issue. I want to create a game-like system in MySQL that would add to *current_energy* **COLUMN** of *users* **TABLE** a defined value regularly over time, for example add 5 to value every 5 minutes have passed.

Is it possible to be done through MySQL itself, or should I look for a way of updating it on, let's say, player login with PHP queries based on *time();* comparation with *last_login* **COLUMN**?

Comment: You can write a PHP script to update the column and add it in crontab configuring it to run every 5 minutes

Comment: Heard of cron jobs?

Comment: @Akin Actually I've never heard of those, I'd try to get some info on it through google in a moment, but at first glance seems like it could solve this problem.

Comment: @SaishSali I'll give it a go in a moment, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it.  You would be scheduling an event or job, just adding load onto your server.

Instead, create a view with the logic such as this:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*,
           current_energy + floor(timestampdiff(minute, last_login, now()) / 5)
    from t;
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick as well, but would it keep on updating it as the user keeps on browsing the game, or would only add this value at login now?

Comment: @DamianDoman . . . This is the basic idea.  You would need to keep the right values in the table to get what you really need.